# ServiceStack - 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.32' and PCL

Tags: servicestack

Trying to Install ServiceStack into a PCL but get the following error:

Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.32'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have the latest nuget package installed.

Any ideas of how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack's [Hello Mobile](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#portable-class-library-support) project contains details about ServiceStack's PCL support where the `ServiceStack.Interfaces` is built against **Profile136** whilst the `ServiceStack.Text` and `ServiceStack.Client` NuGet packages only supports **Profile7**, i.e. PCL support does not include Windows Phone or Silverlight although the NuGet package does include custom builds for Silverlight.

### Portable Class Library support

Most clients make use of ServiceStack's new PCL support which are contained in the following NuGet packages:

- ServiceStack.Interfaces

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.0, Silverlight5, WP8 (Profile136)
- ServiceStack.Client

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.5 (Profile7)
  - Custom builds: NET40, Silverlight 5
- ServiceStack.Text

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.5 (Profile7)
  - Custom builds: NET40, Silverlight 5

You would need to ensure the project you're referencing matches up with the supported PCL Profile.

Comment: Any plans to allow ServiceStack.Interfaces to be used with netstandard PCL's?

Comment: @ChrisKlepeis yes it's being worked on, you can vote for the [.NET Core feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/10286952-support-dnx) to receive notifications on progress.